# How to connect one HingeJoint2D to another HingeJoint2D in code?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

im making a 2D game where you need to swing from one rope to another;
so start position is rope. Your character connected to this rope with HingeJoint and when you start moving your character you can press some button and your character disconnecting with joint.
So i used OnTriggerEnter2D to find next and in this method i need to connect with founded rope.
SO HOW CONNECT WITH JOINT IN CODE

I tried a lot but it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

You need to set one joint as a parent of the other.

On the child joint, set the "Connected Body" property to reference the Rigidbody of the parent joint.

You may then need to configure some limits/springs/motors/etc., but they should be connected.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably chain them.

Like in rope-B set [connectedBody](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Joint-connectedBody.html) to rope-A, and in your player set `connectedBody` to B.

In general a joint is always either connected to an `Rigidbody` or a world space anchor => you need to `AddComponent` and `Destroy` it on your player!